# Terraform provisioner local-exec - aws cli

Tags: terraform, aws-cli

Trying to use AWS cli to `put-public-access-block` on an `s3` bucket but running into an issue and cannot work it out.

This is my code;

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test" {
  bucket = "blah-blah"

  versioning {
    enabled = false
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
        apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
            sse_algorithm = "AES256"
        }
    }
  }

  tags {
    Name = "blah-blah"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "s3publicpol" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws s3api put-public-access-block --bucket blah-blah --public-access-block-configuration BlockPublicAcls=true,IgnorePublicAcls=true,BlockPublicPolicy=true,RestrictPublicBuckets=true"
  }   
}
```

When running this from terraform I am getting this message;

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutPublicAccessBlock operation: Access Denied

But when I try and run AWS cli and run the command above myself it works perfectly fine, so I have the permissions within AWS.

Am I missing something I need to do locally for Terraform?

Cheers
Stephen

Comment: What account are you running the terraform under? Is it your account or a different one? If it is a different one, does it have the correct permissions?

Comment: I am running this from an EC2 instance, with a role which assumes administrator access in another account, unless it is something to do with that? But I have manually switched roles and done this via the management GUI, the provider for AWS specifies the role in the other account - bit lots as to what is causing this

Comment: your code worked for me running Terraform from my command line.  I would look at the assume role.

Comment: Thanks for having a look, wondering if there could be something not obvious on this like a canned ACL stopping cross account or something - I'll go back and have a look at my permissions least I know this should work!

Answer (score 1):

The [aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_public_access_block.html) resource is now natively supported in Terraform:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.id

  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}
```